# How to remove tag span, space, new line character in Thymeleaf conditional code block?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.5.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 3.0.11.RELEASE (thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar), Thymeleaf Spring 3.0.11.RELEASE (thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar)

code snippet

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${employeeList}">
    <td th:text="${employee.order}"></td>
    <td th:text="${employee.age}"></td>
    <td th:switch="${employee.level}">
        <span th:case="0">Junior</span>
        <span th:case="1">Senior</span>
        <span th:case="2">Expert</span>
    </td>
    <td th:text="${employee.activeStatus}"></td>
</tr>
```

For sorting in data-grid by JavaScript, I need remove `<span></span>` tag pairs. For example, if an employee has level = 2. This time, Thymeleaf will render

```
<td><span>Expert<span></td>
```

I hope it become to

```
<td>Expert</td>
```

(without `<span>` tag). How to to this?

I also try

```
<tr th:each="employee : ${employeeList}">
    <td th:text="${employee.order}"></td>
    <td th:text="${employee.age}"></td>
    <td th:switch="${employee.level}">
        <th:block th:case="'0'">Junior</th:block>
        <th:block th:case="'1'">Senior</th:block>
        <th:block th:case="'2'">Expert</th:block>
    </td>
    <td th:text="${employee.activeStatus}"></td>
</tr>
```

But It generate unwanted character

```
<td>


Expert
</td>
```

(Has new line or space before text, It is not wanted result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, you shouldn't care about the extra spaces & newlines.  HTML ignores those spaces when rendering, and so it shouldn't matter to you -- and there is no way to get rid of them short of formatting hacks.

If you really want to get rid of the spaces you could:

1. Put the switch on one line.

   ```
   <tr th:each="employee : ${employeeList}">
       <td th:text="${employee.order}"></td>
       <td th:text="${employee.age}"></td>
       <td th:switch="${employee.level}"><th:block th:case="'0'">Junior</th:block><th:block th:case="'1'">Senior</th:block><th:block th:case="'2'">Expert</th:block></td>
       <td th:text="${employee.activeStatus}"></td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. Create a `Map<String, String> levelToDescription`, put it on the model, and use that instead of a switch statement.

   ```
   <tr th:each="employee : ${employeeList}">
       <td th:text="${employee.order}" />
       <td th:text="${employee.age}" />
       <td th:text="${levelToDescription[employee.level]}" />
       <td th:text="${employee.activeStatus}" />
   </tr>
   ```

Etc...

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<td th:switch="${employee.level}">
    <th:block th:case="'0'">Junior</th:block>
    <th:block th:case="'1'">Senior</th:block>
    <th:block th:case="'2'">Expert</th:block>
</td>
```

by

```
<th:block th:if="${employee.level} eq '0'"><td>Junior</td></th:block>
<th:block th:if="${employee.level} eq '1'"><td>Senior</td></th:block>
<th:block th:if="${employee.level} eq '2'"><td>Expert</td></th:block>
```